# Error : WebView has been removed from react native

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I built new React Native project yesterday using react-native-cli. But when running the project with my android phone, I got this error in red screen.

> Invariant Violation: WebView has been removed from React Native. It
>   can now be installed and imported from 'react-native-webview' instead
>   of 'react-native'. See
>   'https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview'.

[image: scri]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your scenario Old WebView is now deprecated for better performance and to reduce package sizes. You can find more information about this by [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/webview.html)

**Solution**

Install new WebView Package using this command

```
npm install --save react-native-webview
```

You can find more information regarding package installation from [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md)

After installing above mentioned package now remove old imports and re-import WebView like this

```
import { WebView, } from 'react-native'; //Remove this from your imports

import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'; //Add this to your imports
```